# Spivak, Ch. 20, Prob. *17a: Is the solution manual incorrect?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-explanation, mean-value-theorem

> *17 (a) Show that if $|g'(x)|\leq M|x-a|^n$ for $|x-a|<\delta$, then $|g(x)-g(a)|\leq \frac{M|x-a|^{n+1}}{n+1}$ for $|x-a|<\delta$

Here is the solution in the solution manual

> By hypothesis,
>
> $$-M(x-a)^n\leq g'(x)\leq M(x-a)^n, \text{ for } x\geq a$$
>
> It follows from the Mean Value Theorem that
>
> $$\frac{-M(x-a)^{n+1}}{n+1}\leq g(x)-g(a)\leq
>  \frac{M(x-a)^{n+1}}{n+1}$$
>
> i.e., that $|g(x)-g(a)|\leq \frac{M(x-a)^{n+1}}{n+1}$. The case $x\leq a$ is treated similarly.

Sometimes the solutions are quite terse like this and skip over many steps. Here is my attempt at filling in the intermediate steps in the solution manual solution.

We know that $|g'(x)|\leq M|x-a|^n$ and therefore

$$-M|x-a|^n\leq g'(x)\leq M|x-a|^n$$

If $x\geq a$, then $|x-a|=x-a$ and

$$-M(x-a)^n\leq g'(x)\leq M(x-a)^n\tag{1}$$

The Mean Value Theorem says that there is some point $c\in (a,x)$ at which

$$g'(c)=\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}\tag{2}$$

Hence

$$-M(c-a)^n\leq g'(c)\leq M(c-a)^n$$

But since $x-a>c-a$, and using $(2)$ we have

$$-M(x-a)^n<-M(c-a)^n\leq \frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}\leq M(c-a)^n<M(x-a)^n$$

$$-M(x-a)^{n+1}<g(x)-g(a)<M(x-a)^{n+1}$$

If this is correct so far, **where does the factor $\frac{1}{n+1}$ come from?**

EDIT: As per a comment below, it appears that $(1)$ is simply being integrated. Does the solution manual solution make sense at all? Ie, is there any path that uses MVT?

Comment: the proof doesn't look like it uses MVT to me, it looks like its just integrating from $a$ to $x$

Comment: Without being given that $g'$ is integrable its not possible to do that

Comment: @CSquared - If this problem preceeds proving the FTC in the book, then the problem cannot be solved using it. The MVT is the tool of choice for "integrating" without integration.

Comment: @PaulSinclair The problem does not precede FTC at all. This problem is in Chapter 20, FTC is introduced back in Chapter 14.

Comment: @evianpring - My mistake. They are referring to the [Mean Value Theorem *for integrals*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_definite_integrals) then, not the one for derivatives. The answer to your question is the $\frac 1{n+1}$ it comes from integrating the powers.

Comment: The MVT for integrals also appears in a problem in Spivak (Chapter 13 "Integrals" problem 23d). However, I can't see how to apply it. Would be great to see your suggestion in the form of an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the proof wants to integrate $g'(x)$, but without knowing the integrability of $g'$, it is not possible to directly do that step. Instead for $a+\delta>x \geq a$, consider $F_1(x) = g(x)-g(a)-M(x-a)^{n+1}/n+1$. Then $F_1$ is differentiable on any $[a,x]$ for $x<a+\delta$, and $F_1'(x)\leq 0$. Then by the mean value theorem, $F_1(x)-F_1(a) = F_1(x) = F_1'(c)(x-a) \leq 0$. Using this kind of construction for the other cases you would have the proof.

Answer (score 0):

May be Spivak applies to$$h(x)=\frac{(x-a)^{n+1}}{n+1}$$[the following variant of the mean value theorem](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_des_accroissements_finis#Corollaire) (generalizable to a function $g$ with values in a normed vector space):

> If $g,h:[a,x]\to\mathbb R$ are continuous on $[a,x]$ and differentiable on $(a,x)$ and if
> $$\forall t\in\left]a,x\right[\quad|g'(t)|\le h'(t)$$then$$|g(x)-g(a)|\le h(x)-h(a).$$

Answer (score 0):

Based on the part $b$ portion of this 4-part problem, I would argue that the $\frac{1}{n+1}$ is simply a typo (both in the prompt itself and the solution manual). As you described in your post, using the MVT (outlined in Chapter 11) we can show that:

> If $|g'(x)| \leq M|x-a|^n$ for $|x-a|\lt \delta$, then $|g(x)-g(a)| \lt \left|M(x-a)^{n+1}\right|$

The part $b$ portion of this problem then asks us to use part $a$ in order to show that:

> If $\lim_{x \to a}\frac{g'(x)}{(x-a)^n}=0$, then $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{(x-a)^{n+1}}=0$

Well, by assumption, we have that $\forall \varepsilon \gt 0: \exists \delta_{\varepsilon} \gt 0: \forall x \in (a-\delta_{\varepsilon},a+\delta_{\varepsilon})\setminus \{a\}: \left|\frac{g'(x)}{(x-a)^n}\right| \lt \varepsilon$

Choosing an arbitrary $\varepsilon$, we rewrite the above expression as:

$\forall x \in (a-\delta_{\varepsilon},a+\delta_{\varepsilon})\setminus \{a\}: \left|\frac{g'(x)}{(x-a)^n}\right| \lt \varepsilon \iff \forall x \in (a-\delta_{\varepsilon},a+\delta_{\varepsilon})\setminus \{a\}: |g'(x)| \lt  \varepsilon |(x-a)^n|=\varepsilon|x-a|^n$

Applying part $a$ (as part $b$ suggests in the actual prompt) gives us:

$$|g(x)-g(a)| \lt |\varepsilon (x-a)^{n+1}|=\varepsilon|(x-a)^{n+1}| \iff\left|\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{(x-a)^{n+1}}-0\right|\lt \varepsilon$$

At no point was the $\frac{1}{n+1}$ factor necessary.